# Algorithm of task distribution between peer-to-peer nodes

Tags: algorithm, network-protocols, distributed-computing

I have a problem to distribute tasks between nodes with fully meshed connections. All nodes know about all task and can run any task from list.

Is any protocol or solution to distribute these tasks uniformly between all nodes? I assume that when node is started it learns another peers and take part of their tasks. If node is shutdown other nodes take this node's tasks.

Comment: Task scheduling algorithms generally try to optimize some aspect of job completion, like latency, fairness, locality or throughput.  What traits are you looking for?

Comment: I guess you're looking for `load balancer` implementation!

Comment: Yep, distributed load blancer (without central point).

Comment: @phs limitations doesn't matter. In case of bad (or broken) connection it is okay if this claster will have splitted brain.

Comment: Then [elect a leader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_%28computer_science%29), have it collect incoming work and parcel it out.

Comment: @phs I know algorithm with electing leader but looking for algorithm without it. I pretty clear understand that something possible like: choose id, and take make appropriate subset dividing by number of connection with other nodes. Probably world knows something better.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a head node, you will need for tasks always to be distributed between the nodes, with each node maintaining a task list that contains tasks that are not on any other node's list, to avoid concurrency problems.

One way to distribute the tasks would be for each node to keep an estimation of the time required to complete its assigned tasks.  When a node finds that its estimated time is less than another node's estimated time by more than the time to complete a task, it cooperates with the other node to reassign a task from the other node's list to its own list.